# What is the responsibility of the test department?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I know that many companies have their test department, and I'm asking this question because I can't get some concepts clear.

**1, Are the unit test supposed to be done by the test department/third party enterprise?**

For my own feeling I think this should be done by the developer himself/herself. But there is a saying that said:

*You will tend to test your code in the way you wrote it. So it's better for us to do the unit test. And you are not a professional tester, so you can't make sure your unit test is the best.*

If this is wrong, is there anything official that said a programmer should do the unit test himself?

**2, despite of the unit test, what other tests does the test department do?**

This is kind of a simple question. Maybe there are some random tests, some stress tests, but could anyone give me a list of what the test department do normally?

Comment: It may be better to ask on programmers.se as this is more of a technical Q&A site.

Comment: @ThomasClayson I searched first, there was questions similar like this and are not closed.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you might get a better audience to ask these questions to over there. :)

Comment: @shengy There might be questions like this that aren't closed yet, but this question is off-topic for this site. Programmers.SE would be the right place for this. Voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While developers should test their own work (and they all do, some just use the inefficient "run-test-last-change-fix-run-again" method), there is a psychological problem trying to find your own mistakes:

1. If you knew that you were making a mistake, you would probably try to avoid it. In hindsight, it's often obvious/simple to see a mistake but when it happens, this isn't true. So this creates a "loser" situation where everyone thinks that you're stupid when you actually were trying your best.
2. Every developer has his/her own error pattern; that is everyone makes the same mistakes over and over again. There are various reasons, the most important here is blindness to or unwillingness to admit your own flaws.
3. When you're in a hurry, you start to cut corners. This isn't bad, this is human. The problem is that your memory is already full with all the details that you need for your work. Now the performance of your memory is reduced by stress. This means you will overlook important details **without noticing** - your brain is already working at its limit. And you won't notice that you're missing them. And you won't remember all the ones which you did notice because your memory is in panic mode -> only really important (as in life threatening) information will be processed.
4. Self-surveillance simply doesn't work with humans. You always need an external controller or you will have corruption.

Therefore it makes sense to let someone else test your work:

1. They won't use the same patterns (where to click, in which order to click buttons, how fast you type, ...) which quickly uncovers simple bugs that you can't find yourself, simply because they lie outside your preferred way of using a computer.
2. Their task is to make your life miserable (in a nutshell). If the boss is worth his money, he will create a competitive environment where the developers will try to let as few bugs as possible slip to testing while testing will try to find as many bugs as possible "to show them" (where "them" is the other team). This works really well (human groups love to compete), but you need to be aware of the psychological forces at work. If this isn't managed really well, it will create a lot of stress (-> more bugs slip through), burnout and mutual hatred. If the boss isn't excellent at managing humans, then this *will* backfire.
3. They have different assumptions. They didn't write the code, so they have no idea how it's supposed to work. They will look at your work like a customer and see things that a developer would never care for ("looks ugly", "not responsive enough"). They can find issues which make the product easier to sell. Developers usually only focus on "works well enough" (= doesn't crash when I click the right buttons in exactly the right order).

Now your questions:

> Are the unit test supposed to be done by the test department/third party enterprise?

No. Unit tests are the smallest possible test that you can run on the code but which still has some meaning. The test department should never run those, that's the job of an automated CI server. It's stupid, boring and repetitive work suitable for a computer.

But it makes sense to let the testing dept define new unit tests. Alternatively, error reports from testing should be converted into new unit tests.

> despite of the unit test, what other tests does the test department do?

Some examples:

- They install the actual application like a customer would do (= testing the installer)
- They click everything (especially those parts which they aren't supposed to)
- They run high-level tests on special test databases which contain complex test cases
- They run tests which take hours to complete (unlike unit tests which should execute in a few seconds at most)
- They check that all requirement are met
- They install the product on all kinds of hardware with all supported databases, network layouts, and different configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I feel as though the programmers should have done a good deal of testing themselves but most of that comes down to functionality testing.  Does it work as expected?

The testing/QA people tend to do a deeper job of testing.  Coming from a security background they'll make sure all inputs are validated and nothing is vulnerable to SQL Injections and CSS for example.  Also in larger projects where different teams build different pieces of the finished product the testing department will test the finished product to make sure that no bugs occur during integration including load testing, install testing and testing in various scenarios, different OSes etc.  The testing department needs to know what will happen in every circumstance so that the other teams can determine if it's a bug worth fixing and to let the client base know that it's a known issue or by design.

Lets look at video-games for a second.  In video games you generally have sprites that move all around a designed environment.  A tester will make sure that the sprite stops when it runs into any wall and test it on all possible walls to make sure there isn't any clipping issues.  The developer would generally program the engine and make the map and interactions but wouldn't be concerned with finding individual clipping issues unless they are reported to them.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are written by the developer responsible for writing the code. They're fundamentally for the coder's use. I use them to make sure the code I deliver to QA is free of internal errors like NPEs that would halt testing (as well as make us look bad). Any project is going to have different components that need to work cooperatively, unit tests can make sure the individual components work as expected and that their interactions all function as expected.

Testing by other groups focuses on looking at different aspects of how the product behaves:

- functionality tests check that the business requirements are getting met
- system integration tests check that the program works in a context similar to the production environment
- load tests check that the program will behave as expected when a lot of work is thrown at it
- user experience tests check that normal users will be able to navigate through the UI.

There is a concept of ping-pong TDD, where pair programmers alternate writing tests and code, so you get the benefit of a second person's point of view. That is probably an optimal way of proceeding both for testing and for getting an instantaneous code review, but it freaks management out to think of two employees working on a single task, so opportunities for this are pretty rare. Even without that it's in the programmer's interest to try to break the code with tests. I'd rather break my code when I'm writing it than have somebody else do it later.

Comment: @shengy: yes, NPE=java.lang.NullPointerException